# "Erroneous nesting of equation structures" message- I can't see what's wrong?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, texmaker

I have the following system of equations in Texmaker:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta{_n}),
\\
b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),
 \\
 \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{*}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} = 0,
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{*}_{n+1},
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
\end{split}
\end{align}
\label{system}
\end{equation}
```

When I compile, the following error message is given:"Package amsmath error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures; (amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned`...." However, I can still produce a normal looking PDF file.

I'd be very grateful if someone could point out how to correct this error. I have the amsmath package installed.

Comment: `align` is already in math mode, so get rid of the `equation` environment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not nest `align` in `equation`. The `align` environment is enough:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta{_n}),
\\
b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),
 \\
 \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{*}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} = 0,
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{*}_{n+1},
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
\end{split}
\label{system}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

This compiles (but looks terrible, imho).

With horizontal alignment it looks better I think:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Without alignment:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta{_n}),
\\
b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),
 \\
 \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{*}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} = 0,
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{*}_{n+1},
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
\end{split}
\label{system}
\end{align}

With alignment:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} &= a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta{_n}),
\\
b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) &= b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),
 \\
 \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{*}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} &= 0,
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} &= \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{*}_{n+1},
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} &= \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
\end{split}
\label{system2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what would you do to make it look less "terrrible"? @Skillmon

Comment: @Alex I would add a `&` to all the `=` in the `split`-environment. This way, the `=` get horizontally aligned, which makes the appearance clearer, imho.

Comment: What's the usefulness of split nested in align?

Comment: @Bernard the placement of the equation number in the vertical center. If it's wanted, I think `split` is really handy (and I just didn't remove it from the question)

Comment: @Skillmon: Oh! yes. Usually I do that with `equation+aligned` (or `+split`), so it seemed strange to me.

Answer (score 9):

`align` already puts you in math mode, so get rid of the redundant `equation` environment.  I also moved the `\label` inside the `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta{_n}),
\\
b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),
 \\
 \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{*}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} = 0,
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{*}_{n+1},
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
\end{split}
\label{system}
\end{align}
%\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can keep the `equation` environment, and change `align` to `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
  a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta{_n}),
\\
b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),
 \\
 \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{*}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} = 0,
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{*}_{n+1},
 \\
 \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
\end{split}
\label{system}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem when I had $$\begin{align}.....\end{align}$$. Getting rid of the $$ allowed it to typeset seamlessly

Comment: @user71207 It is a common enough mistake for beginners to LaTeX.  Another is to use `$$` at all.  That is a construct for TeX, and while LaTeX does not complain of it, you instead, when needed, should use `\[...\]` or the `amsmath` package `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` when the equation is not to be numbered, and `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` when it is to be numbered.   The various `amsmath` align-style environments are for when multiple equations reside in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Youn don't have to nest `align` `equation`. If you want a single equation number, nest `aligned` or `split`, but not both, and use `&` for the alignment point. I suggest three possible layouts: either with `aligned` and the second,  very long, line split with `multlined` from `mathtools`, or with `gathered` and `multlined` (no alignment point), or `aligned` but for the second line:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} & = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta_{n}), \\ b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) & = \begin{multlined}[t] b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) \\+ \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),\end{multlined} \\%
  \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} & = 0, \\%
   \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} & = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{}_{n+1}, \\%
   \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} & = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
 \end{aligned}\label{system}
 \end{equation}
\bigskip
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
 a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta_{n}), \\ b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = \begin{multlined}[t] b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) \\+ \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),\end{multlined} \\%
  \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} = 0, \\%
   \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{}_{n+1}, \\%
   \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1}= \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
 \end{gathered}\label{system}
 \end{equation}
\bigskip
 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 a(t_{n+1}) \cos \varphi_{n+1} & = a(t_{n}) \cos \varphi_{n} + \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1} - t_{n}) \cos( \alpha_{n}+ \theta_{n}), \\ %
\MoveEqLeft[2]\mathclap{b(t_{n+1})\sin \varphi_{n+1} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n+1} \right) = b(t_{n})\sin \varphi_{n} \left(1+ \delta \sin^{2} \varphi_{n} \right) \mathrlap{+ \sqrt{2E_{n}}(t_{n+1}-t_{n}) \sin (\alpha_{n} + \theta_{n}),}} \\%
    \theta_{n} + \alpha_{n} + \theta^{}_{n+1} - \alpha_{n+1} & = 0, \\%
     \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\cos \theta_{n+1} & = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\cos\theta^{}_{n+1}, \\%
     \sqrt{2E_{n+1}}\sin\theta_{n+1} & = \sqrt{2E_{n}}\sin\theta^{*}_{n+1}-2u(\varphi_{n+1}, t_{n+1}).
 \end{aligned}\label{system}
 \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]